# MS Access - sum of duplicate values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, analytics

I have multiple data rows with same Invoice_ID code (xxx-ccc-aaa) but for two rows the values are the same (0.4).

My sum query doesn't take into account the second 0.4 value.
Is there a way to edit the calculation in access?

Data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H2VE.png)

Current results: 1.70
Expected results: 1.74

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359195/share-a-table-on-stack-overflow-for-easy-import-into-ms-access) for how to share a table. We can't import an image

Comment: You probably have a DISTINCT or DISTINCTROW in the queries/query you use to sum the amounts. Remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was bit more complex. Main query was working on a query that was doing a UNION operation. That eliminated duplicate rows, after changing to UNION ALL the issue got resolved.